# ItemInventoryQuery is not returning all the available fields.

Tags: qbxml, qbfc, qbwc

We are using Web Connector on the end where QBPOS 10.0 is installed.

On the server end we issue an ItemInventoryQuery request using QBPOSFC3.0 (QB POS Foundation Classes).

The response we receive from Quickbooks contains most of the fields available on an inventory item, but there are some fields that are not being returned, specifically, "Unit of Measure" is not being returned on the XML we receive from Quickbooks.

Per the on screen reference, the "UnitOfMeasure" is a field available on the response of an ItemInventoryQuery
https://member.developer.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/Common/newOSR/index.html

Nonetheless I am unable to obtain these values, the "UnitOfMeasure" nodes do not even exist on the XML response we get from Quickbooks, everything else is good in the response (e.g. item ListID, name, vendor, etc.)

What am I missing here ?

Here is a sample of the XML response we receive:
http://pastebin.com/pA6KDr0k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked some of my old source code and found that I was explicitly telling it which fields to return. For example:

```
query.IncludeRetElementList.Add("UnitOfMeasure1");
query.IncludeRetElementList.Add("UnitOfMeasure2");
query.IncludeRetElementList.Add("UnitOfMeasure3");
```

I don't remember if I did this because of the same problem you're having, but I do know I got the UOM fields in the response. Hope this helps!

Comment: I will definitely try this and get back with the results.

Comment: This worked for me ! Using this list produces an XML response exactly with the fields requested on this list (and the rest is excluded), so if you don't use the list, you have to also include all the previous fields you were relying on. 

So this worked a charm for me. Also for the records UnitOfMeasure is only available on QBXML 2.0 and above.

Answer (score 1):

Check unit of measure is enabled for the company file in preferences -> items & inventory -> Company preferences tab. It is disabled by default in new companies.

Comment: Although I see some "Unit of measure" options in preferences, I don't see anything that would involve sending this information along to integrated applications or something like that.

Comment: @AgustinGarzon There is no separate control for UofM in integrated applications. Rather, the enable/disable UofM controls whether UofM fields appear anywhere in QB (including integrations) for that company file.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing other fields too such as time created.

If you included any IncludeRetElementList lines in your request that will limit your results.
So You will have to add IncludeRetElements for UOM as Mike suggested.

If that doesn't work I'd suggest posting your request.